# match eliminating white space mongodb aggregate function

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

The object in MongoDB database looks like this which includes city names that have spaces in between -

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("65ofb9104b1cf1519e4c5957"),
    "country": "us",
    "city": "New York"
}
```

I would like to make a case insensitive search on the city names eliminating their white spaces.
Ex: matching for `newyork` should return all the documents with `New York` as a city name. So far, I have tried the following query which does the case insensitive search but it does not eliminate space in between.

```
db.getCollection('cities').aggregate([
        { $match: { "city": { '$regex':  'newyork' , $options: 'i' } } } , 
]);
```

Comment: You could use [`"$replaceAll"`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceAll/) on `"city"` to eliminate spaces.

Comment: yes, i am having problem understanding the syntax of using `regex`and `replace all` together. I tried this but it throws error - `{ $match: { '$replaceAll': { input: { "city": { '$regex':  'newyork' , $options: 'i' } , find: " ", replacement: "" } } } }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to accomplish this space/case insensitive search/`"$match"`.  Perhaps one of the options below, or a small modification, will satisfy your requirements.

Example collection used with examples below:

```json
  [
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("650fb9104b1cf1519e4c5957"),
      "country": "us",
      "city": "New York"
    },
    {
      "_id": ObjectId("650fb9104b1cf1519e4c5958"),
      "country": "us",
      "city": "Los Angeles"
    }
  ]
```

This will `"$match"` your lowercase search string to a space-removed, lowercased `"city"`.

```js
db.cities.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$eq": [
          {
            "$toLower": {
              "$replaceAll": {
                "input": "$city",
                "find": " ",
                "replacement": ""
              }
            }
          },
          "newyork"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("650fb9104b1cf1519e4c5957"),
    "city": "New York",
    "country": "us"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CLZ9eQhJ98X).

This will `"$match"` a case insensitive `"regex"` to a space-removed `"city"`.

```js
db.cities.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "$expr": {
        "$regexMatch": {
          "input": {
            "$replaceAll": {
              "input": "$city",
              "find": " ",
              "replacement": ""
            }
          },
          "regex": "sang",
          "options": "i"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("650fb9104b1cf1519e4c5958"),
    "city": "Los Angeles",
    "country": "us"
  }
]
```

Try it on [mongoplayground.net](https://mongoplayground.net/p/xReTQNnC6sE).